# Bingmaps MapServiceToken issue

Tags: uwp, bing-maps

I'm trying to add a map on my UWP app but I get a warning stating that the Service Token was not specified. I followed tried to follow the instruction from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key but I don't get the "Windows Application" option. I only get these three:

[image]

I tried with all three options with no luck. What's the correct way to proceed in this case???

Cheers!

Comment: Nope, just the three described in the image above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't get the "Windows Application" option. I only get these three

For the testing, I can get **Windows Application** option in the drop-box, and above screenshot looks that the web page has not load complete. Please try to clean the browser's cache. And you could also try to use other browser to open this link and please make sure the developer account was login.

Comment: I tried with Windows Edge and that did the trick. Thanks a lot, man!!